# Replacement for Greatest/Least in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm trying to convert an Oracle view to SQL Server. One part of it has the following statement:

```
GREATEST (SYSDATE -(status.status_date + LEAST (status.days_before_past_due, 999999)), 0)
AS wo_actual_days_past_due,
```

I know there are no direct replacements for the GREATEST and LEAST functions. I found another thread on here where somebody suggested something like the following:

```
(select max(tmp) from (
    select 1 tmp from dual
    union all
    select 2 tmp from dual
    union all
    select 3 tmp from dual
    union all
    select 4 tmp from dual
    union all
    select 5 tmp from dual
    union all
    select 6 tmp from dual
    union all
    select 7 tmp from dual
) ) AS number
```

I tried this but it gets pretty crazy having 2 of these together. Here's what I came up with:

```
(SELECT MAX(C1) 
from (
select (GETDATE -(status.status_date + 

(SELECT MIN(C2)
    from (
        select status.days_before_past_due C2 from dual
        union all 
        select 999999 C2 from dual
    ) as temp

) ) ) C1 from dual
union all
select 0 C1 from dual
) as wo_actual_days_past_due,
```

But that's not working for me. I'm getting "Invalid column name" for GETDATE. Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do here? Is there a better way? And how can I fix the "Invalid column name" issue?

Comment: Maybe you need `GETDATE()`

Comment: For two values, I'd use case expressions instead of subqueries. `LEAST(A, B)` becomes `case when A < B then A else B end`. Add appropriate logic for nulls. You might also need the `dateadd` and `datediff` functions. SQL Server doesn't like direct arithmetic on `datetime` as much as Oracle does on `date`.

Comment: And what is `LEAST (status.days_before_past_due, 999999)` doing? Do you ever have something that is more than 999,999 days (~2, 737 years) until past due and you really need to use a smaller number?

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that in Azure SQL DB and SQL Server 2022+ have greatest and least functions in the langauge.

[GREATEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
[LEAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-least-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current)